# rails 3 route path building issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, url-routing

I have such route:

```
scope ':property', :constraints => { :property => /inv|um|tm|pp/ } do
      resources :user_templates do
        member do
          get 'download/:idcreated', :action => 'download'
        end
      end
end
```

In browser `http://127.0.0.1:3000/inv/user_templates/6/download/12?locale=uk`, it works.

But How can I build resource path?

I tried:

```
download_user_template_path(params[:property], @id, @idcreated)
```

but I got that message:

```
No route matches {:action=>"download", :controller=>"user_templates", :locale=>:uk, :property=>"inv", :id=>76, :format=>6}
```

It doesn't work too:

`download_user_template_path('property' => params[:property], 'id' => @tmp_id, 'idcreated' => @created_temp_row[:id])`

```
rake routes

                  GET    /:property/user_templates/:id/download/:idcreated(.:format) {:property=>/inv|um|tm|pp/, :action=>"download", :controller=>"user_templates"}
   user_templates GET    /:property/user_templates(.:format){:property=>/inv|um|tm|pp/, :action=>"index", :controller=>"user_templates"}
                  POST   /:property/user_templates(.:format){:property=>/inv|um|tm|pp/, :action=>"create", :controller=>"user_templates"}
new_user_template GET    /:property/user_templates/new(.:format){:property=>/inv|um|tm|pp/, :action=>"new", :controller=>"user_templates"}
edit_user_template GET    /:property/user_templates/:id/edit(.:format){:property=>/inv|um|tm|pp/, :action=>"edit", :controller=>"user_templates"}
     user_template GET    /:property/user_templates/:id(.:format){:property=>/inv|um|tm|pp/, :action=>"show", :controller=>"user_templates"}
                   PUT    /:property/user_templates/:id(.:format){:property=>/inv|um|tm|pp/, :action=>"update", :controller=>"user_templates"}
                   DELETE /:property/user_templates/:id(.:format){:property=>/inv|um|tm|pp/, :action=>"destroy", :controller=>"user_templates"}
```

Any help plz?

Comment: What does `rake routes` show for the route in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add  :as => :download, and use rake routes CONTROLLER= ...